EXR Format and HDR for Post-Processing - Does rendering to EXR preserve information beyond the visible range for post-processing?
Does rendering to EXR preserve information beyond the visible range for post-processing?
I’m planning to render my scene to an EXR file in Blender with a higher bit depth, and I’m wondering if that will help preserve information beyond the visible range. My main goal is to capture the full dynamic range so that I can do some detailed post-processing later, either in Blender or another software.
What I’m aiming to do is:

Render to EXR to get the most detail possible.
Use Blender’s compositor to handle the post-processing.
Finally, save the processed image as a JPG with 90% quality.

Does rendering to EXR with higher bit depth actually help in retaining that extra information for post-processing? And is there a smooth way to handle this entire workflow directly in Blender?

Yes, EXR is a lossless format so whatever data is present in your scene/render should be preserved. Converting to JPEG will clamp that data ofc, but that should be after processing so it won't matter.
